# How to automatically collapse repetitive log output in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Every once in a while, a server or database error causes thousands of the same stack trace in the server log files.  It might be a different error/stacktrace today than a month ago.  But it causes the log files to rotate completely, and I no longer have visibility into what happened before.  (Alternately, I don't want to run out of disk space, which for reasons outside my control right now is limited--I'm addressing that issue separately).  At any rate, I don't need thousands of copies of the same stack trace--just a dozen or so should be enough.

I would like it if I could have log4j/log4j2/another system automatically collapse repetitive errors, so that they don't fill up the log files.  For example, a threshold of maybe 10 or 100 exceptions from the same place might trigger log4j to just start counting, and wait until they stop coming, then output a count of how many more times they appeared.

What pre-made solutions exist (a quick survey with links is best)?  If this is something I should implement myself, what is a good pattern to start with and what should I watch out for?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried expanding the size and/or quantity of log files?  Also, the real solution to your problem appears to fix the thing that is causing all the stacktraces.

Comment: @DwB, As I mentioned in the original question, I don't have a lot of control over the VM disk size (a decision mostly out of my hands, which is being addressed separately); To the other part of your suggestion on fixing the causes of the stack traces: yes of course that's a given, but we don't live in an ideal world; especially when the system has integration points and dependencies that go down outside my control, and I am not necessarily given the time I'd like to fix all the things.  Also, as I also said--the point is to retain logs when I have UNexpected error output.

Comment: @KimballRobinson: did you find any good existing solution for this? It will be great if you could share some input and how you eventually solved this.

Comment: @SurjanSRawat - I never really solved it directly; I probably solved the bug and tuned the logs.  If I tackled this today, I would: (A) look at BurstFilter as others suggest; (B) Create monitoring/alerting so I can respond faster; (C) custom log decorator+sampler strategy pattern (presumably BurstFilter does this); (D) Siphon offending class/loggers to a separate file/index that rolls faster; (E)  Centralized logging, alerting can alleviate this too.  Honestly, this is a problem of getting faster engineering response/capture, and fixing bugs sooner.

Comment: @SurjanSRawat Also note - I moved on to other technologies: logback is better IMHO; also my org has centralized logging.   I also switched to entirely different tech stacks.

Comment: @SurjanSRawat or any others with similar questions - Thinking about this more deeply, it seems wise to use a logging strategy based on selected *transactions* - so I would probably have a correlation property or MDC property set that filters logging based on some sampling strategy, (IE mark one transaction per 10 seconds to sample).

Answer (score 4):

Will the [BurstFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#BurstFilter/) do what you want? If not, please create a Jira issue with the algorithm that would work for you and the Log4j team would be happy to consider it. Better yet, if you can provide a patch it would be much more likely to be incorporated.

Comment: That looks fairly close to what I am looking for, although I'd like to further restrict it by line number or method name (e.g. only filter similar messages with the same origin).   Still, this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Log4j's BurstFilter will certainly help prevent you filling your disks. Remember to configure it so that it applies in as limited a section of code as you can, or you'll filter out messages you might want to keep (that is, don't use it on your appender, but on a particular logger that you isolate in your code).

I wrote a simple utility class at one point that wrapped a logger and filtered based on n messages within a given Duration.  I used instances of it around most of my warning and error logs to protect the off chance that I'd run into problems like you did.  It worked pretty well for my situation, especially because it was easier to quickly adapt for different situations.

Something like:

```
...

public DurationThrottledLogger(Logger logger, Duration throttleDuration, int maxMessagesInPeriod) {
   ...
}

public void info(String msg) {
    getMsgAddendumIfNotThrottled().ifPresent(addendum->logger.info(msg + addendum));
}


private synchronized Optional<String> getMsgAddendumIfNotThrottled() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String msgAddendum;
    if (throttleDuration.compareTo(Duration.between(lastInvocationTime, now)) <= 0) {
        // last one was sent longer than throttleDuration ago - send it and reset everything
        if (throttledInDurationCount == 0) {
            msgAddendum = " [will throttle future msgs within throttle period]";
        } else {
            msgAddendum = String.format(" [previously throttled %d msgs received before %s]",
                    throttledInDurationCount, lastInvocationTime.plus(throttleDuration).format(formatter));
        }
        totalMessageCount++;
        throttledInDurationCount = 0;
        numMessagesSentInCurrentPeriod = 1;
        lastInvocationTime = now;
        return Optional.of(msgAddendum);
    } else if (numMessagesSentInCurrentPeriod < maxMessagesInPeriod) {
        msgAddendum = String.format(" [message %d of %d within throttle period]", numMessagesSentInCurrentPeriod + 1, maxMessagesInPeriod);
        // within throttle period, but haven't sent max messages yet - send it
        totalMessageCount++;
        numMessagesSentInCurrentPeriod++;
        return Optional.of(msgAddendum);
    } else {
        // throttle it
        totalMessageCount++;
        throttledInDurationCount++;
        return emptyOptional;
    }
}
```

I'm pulling this from an old version of the code, unfortunately, but the gist is there. I wrote a bunch of static factory methods that I mainly used because they let me write a single line of code to create one of these for that one log message:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
     DurationThrottledLogger.error(logger, Duration.ofSeconds(1), "Received IO Exception. Exiting current reader loop iteration.", e);
}
```

This probably won't be as important in your case; for us, we were using a somewhat underpowered graylog instance that we could hose down fairly easily.